# Finding the left-most and right-most points of a list. std::find_if the right way to go?

Tags: c++, stl, find, comparator

I have a list of Point objects, (each one with x,y properties) and would like to find the left-most and right-most points. I've been trying to do it with find_if, but i'm not sure its the way to go, because i can't seem to pass a comparator instance. Is find_if the way to go? Seems not. So, is there an algorithm in `<algorithm>` to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef struct Point{
        float x;
        float y;
} Point;

bool left(Point& p1,Point& p2)
{
        return p1.x < p2.x;

}
int main(){
        Point p1 ={-1,0};
        Point p2 ={1,0};
        Point p3 ={5,0};
        Point p4 ={7,0};

        list <Point> points;

        points.push_back(p1);
        points.push_back(p2);
        points.push_back(p3);
        points.push_back(p4);

        //Should return an interator to p1.
        find_if(points.begin(),points.end(),left);                                                  

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` instead.

```
list<Point>::iterator left = std::min_element(points.begin(), points.end(), left);
list<Point>::iterator right = std::max_element(points.begin(), points.end(), left);
```

I would also change the signature of `left` to:

```
bool left(const Point& p1, const Point& p2)
```

Comment: Thanks. Had to create a struct left{bool operator(){...}}; to make it work

Comment: @Tom The problem seems to be that the name `left` clashes with something, if I change the function name to `foo` I don't need a functor but can pass the function directly.

Comment: +1 If performance is a concern you can write your own algorithm that does both in a single pass over the list and returns a pair of min/max.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `pair<float, float>` instead of your own `Point`, there's no need for a special comparator. There would also be an ordering on the y-axis of points with the same x-coordinate, which can be useful.

There are various ways to imbue `typedef pair<float, float> Point;` with custom behavior, if you're so inclined. For example,

```
typedef pair<float, float> Point;

enum AxisUnit { x, y };
float &operator*( Point &p, AxisUnit c ) // "special case" of inner product
     { return c == x? p.first : p.second; }

Point my_point( 2.5, 6.3 );
float x_coord = my_point * x;
```

Answer (score 0):

even better would be to use the boost minmax element:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/algorithm/minmax/index.html

```
#include <boost/algorithm/minmax_element.hpp>
...
auto res = boost::minmax_element(points.begin(), points.end(), left);

std::cout << "min: " << res.first << std::endl;
std::cout << "max: " << res.second << std::endl;
```